# Mac, known_hosts location not default?

Tags: macos, ssh

I developped a software in Java for some customers and my soft needs to access the known_hosts file since it's using JSCH commands. I tested it on my computer running on Linux and several Mac machines and it works fine. But I have an issue with one customer :

My soft can't access the known_hosts file. I know that its default location (and mostly always) is  : /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts

BUT

when I asked him to type in the terminal nano /users/username/.ssh/known_hosts it created a new file instead of opening one.
So my question is :

Is it possible for the known_hosts file to be somewhere else ? If so, how do you find it's location ???

NB : I have no remote access to the Mac (like with TeamViewer or things like that) since it is not connected to internet.

Answer (score 5):

Since the default location may be overridden for a particular host through entries in `~/.ssh/config`, you need to determine the file *for a particular target*.

MacOS uses a recent enough version of openSSH that you should be able to use the `-G` option to determine configuration for a particular connection:

```
$ ssh -G somehost | grep knownhostsfile
globalknownhostsfile /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
userknownhostsfile ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts2
```

Rather than editing a file with `nano` or any other text editor, the correct way to create a known_hosts file would be to *make a successful connection* using SSH, and answer the SSH client's challenge about correctness of the host key.

If you want to impress your client with your sensitivity to security requirements he may not even know he has, then rather than asking him to type a pathname, send him an `ssh` command line along with the intended key for him to verify, so that he can confidently say "Yes, this is the right host." Let SSH do its job.

Comment: I'm in aweird situation: I deleted my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, where I previously set an alias for a machine, but the `ssh` command still find it. The command you suggested shows four locations (and four `*known_hosts` files), but no one of those file exist. But still, if I `ssh` to my equivalent of `somehost`, it succesfully try to connect to it. Also rebooting do not work. Any suggestion on where `ssh` still find `somehost` name?

Comment: Hej @VincenzoLavorini .. The most likely places to find hostnames are DNS, `/etc/hosts`, and your `~/.ssh/config` file. The `known_hosts` file doesn't keep aliases or configuration, it's merely a cache of host keys. Deleting that file will cause subsequent `ssh` attempts to prompt you to answer "yes/no" to accept the host key as valid. If this doesn't help, you might want to ask your question on http://SuperUser.com/ with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default location – the file may simply not exist yet because it was never used (macOS does this quite often; `/etc/fstab` is another example).

But if you create this file and add any hosts to it (and set the correct permissions; `0700` on `~/.ssh` and `0600` on `~/.ssh/known_hosts`) they will be recognised.